# How to check by jQuery the value some checked checkboxes attribute value?

Tags: jquery

I need some help, I have some checkboxes like that

```
<input class="some-class" type="checkbox" has-format="0">
```

or

```
<input class="some-class" type="checkbox" has-format="1">
```

Is it possible, to check, if all of that checked checkboxes has the `has-format` value = 1 or 0 ? I mean, e.g. if I want to check = 1 then if any of the checked checkboxes has that value 0 then I'll get false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the `:checked` selector with the attribute selector. The following variable is only `true` if all of the specified conditions are met.

```
var checked_and_format1 = !$('.some-class:checked[has-format!=1]').length;
// Selects:
//  .some-class 
//  which is checked
// and has a `has-format` property which is not 1.
// If the collection's size is zero, then we can assume that the whole
//  .some-class:checked collection is valid.
```

If you're sure that there's no other value besides 1 and 0, you can replace `[has-format!=1]` with `[has-format=0]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var isValid = $('.some-class:checked[has-format="0"]').length == 0;
```